# Configurar rota de chegada no pfsense

Tags: apache, tomcat, dns, grails

Galera estou tentando colocar minha aplicação no ar, mas não faço ideia de que caminho prosseguir.

É um servidor desenvolvido em grails, já gerei o .war e ele roda em cima do tomcat7, quando acesso localmente e ou de outras maquinas da mesma rede ele esta funcionando.

Porem para eu acessar de outra maquina em qualquer lugar do mundo sei que tenho que configurar a rota no servidor de borda da minha rede, no caso tenho o pfsense instalado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sei o ip real da minha maquina atraves do site https://www.whatismyip.com/.

Porem quando acesso esse ip pela porta 8080 nada é encontrado, o que falta eu configurar? Tenho que ter algum dns registrado?

**UPDATE**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Alteração sugerida**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Cai na tela de login do pfsense

Comment: Faça um teste, de dentro da rede tente acessar 192.168.1.95:8080 e veja se conecta. É que por padrão o Tomcat "ouve" apenas a interface localhost (127.0.0.1), daí você terá de editar a inicialização dele e colocar algo como "0.0.0.0" para que ele "ouça" todas as interfaces de rede.

Comment: Acessa sim, de qualquer maquina minha da rede interna a minha aplicação. Se eu coloco meu ip real no browser ele cai na tela de login do pfsense, E se eu coloco na porta 8080 nada acontece.

Comment: Coloque "Enable ( NAT+Proxy )" na opção "NAT Reflection" resolve.

Comment: Giovani ja esta essa opção, e ainda assim nada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo você tem que usar o "Port Forwarding" (Encaminhamento de porta) do seu Roteador, nele você vai encaminhar tudo que chegar procurando pela porta 8080 para sua maquina, e fácil de configurar você coloca o ip da maquina e a porta, procure no manual do seu roteador.

É preciso verificar também o firewall do seu sistema operacional se a porta 8080 esta aberta ok?

No entanto tem um problema se sua internet não tiver IP fixo, toda vez que sua for reconectada o seu IP irá mudar, para isso você pode usar serviços como do no-ip que faz o direcionamento automático para um endereço fixo (seusite.no-ip.algumacoisa) com uso de um programinha que envia seu novo IP para um DNS online.

Mas eu recomendo que você arranje uma hospedagem paga (você acha tomcat por 9,90 mês por ai + um banco de dados e sua aplicação é publica sem dor de cabeça), se colocar na balança sai mais barato contratar uma hospedagem do que manter uma maquina ligada em casa 24 por 7 e com conexão de internet confiável, desgastando sua maquina, consumindo energia e internet além de expor sua rede a perigos de segurança, considere isso.

Comment: Sim é isso que estou tentando to na aba Firewall/NAT/Port Forward do pfsense mas não consigo liberar o acesso de jeito maneira

Comment: Ha e o firewall do windows esta desligado

Comment: o ip 192.168.1.95 está fixo na sua maquina? você consegue ver o tomcat de outra maquina dentro da rede acessando esse ip? confira primeiro o acesso intranet pode ser que tenha algo errado na sua maquina.

Comment: sim é sim, por outra maquina na rede acesso por esse ip e vejo minha aplicação rodando sucesso

Comment: faz um teste ai, em destination port range coloca porta 80 para 8080 e tenta acessar pelo navegador direto no ip sem colocar o numero de porta no final (:8080)

Comment: já tentei colocar htpps tbm

Comment: teste se suas portas 80 e 8080 estao abertas neste scanner online http://www.t1shopper.com/tools/port-scan/ alguns roteadores você tem que liberar a porta em uma configuração, e depois fazer o redirecionamento, pode ser que sua porta apesar de redirecionada não foi liberada. Veja se tem opção de firewall no seu roteador que habilite essas portas

Comment: A interface estava errada